# Have there been any significant improvements to methods of transporting hydrogen to the surface of Mars in the last 10 years?

Tags: mars, isru

I have just been reading “Human missions to Mars: enabling technologies for the red planet” by Donald Rapp (Praxis publishing 2008). According to this book one major challenge facing a future manned mars landing is transportation of hydrogen to the surface of Mars for ISRU. But this book is 10 years old. Has any significant progress been made on this issue since then?

I believe the main issues are the amount of insulation that can be applied, its weight and its effectiveness at reducing boil off, especially on the surface of Mars v the possibilities for active refrigeration and the complexity and power consumption of such a refrigeration system.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but what has been discovered is more evidence of ice near the surface of Mars in many areas.  Given that, and enough power, you can make hydrogen there.

Comment: Yes I was aware that there had been discoveries of ice near the surface. However could these be relied upon for a first mission? How accessable are they, how easy to extract from the regolith, what impurities are they mixed with and how might these be removed? No doubt these issues can all be resolved fairly easily, but on a first mission? Would this mission critical element be left to chance?

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabatier_reaction can generate the return fuel for the Mars trip back home to earth, if you have the hydrogen, either from Earth, or ISRU from Mars if you had water ice.    The 1200kt of return fuel for one spacex Starship seems to require ~67kt of hydrogen if you use pyrolysis to separate the methane back into Hydrogen and graphite, where the pyrolysis hydrogen gets returned to the Sabatier reactor to make more oxygen and methane since Starship uses 77% oxygen and 22% methane.

Comment: @Sheldon, yes true, but the point in question is how easy would it be to transport hydrogen from Earth to Mars with todays technology? And the related question how reliably could pure water (and hence hydrogen) be extracted from the surface of Mars? Once the hydrogen is available in tanks in whatever form on the surface of Mars the rest is just chemistry and energy availability. Note sure why you would use pyrolysis on methane?

Comment: @Slarty It sure seems like some pretty high Tech Martian chemistry is required for the trip back home to Earth, plus the transpiration of the H2 from Earth.

Comment: @Sheldon the biggest problem on Mars is transporting the hydrogen (or isolating pure water on the surface) hence my original question. There is no complex chemistry required for the trip back home the Sabatier reaction is gas light era chemistry and is well established in industrial chemical processes.

Comment: @slarty -- I'm new to the ISRU topic; thanks for being onthe space stackexchange website and helping educate me.    It seems that the chemistry for ISRU methane via the Sabatier family of reactions is reasonable and the limiting problems are Hydrogen transport or Martian water, and maybe Martian solar power.

Comment: @Sheldon your welcome. And yes the two available approaches are transportation of liquid hydrogen to the surface OR water extraction on the surface followed by the need for vast amounts of power for electrolysis to produce hydrogen.